# Tumble Dryer Capacitor

Tags: capacitor

need to replace my tumble dryer capacitor but most I see seem a different spec, most seem to be 8uf, am I right at saying looking at the picture it is 0.1uf? Its for a White Knight Eco43A gas tumble dryer. Really Ive been looking online but can't seem to find where I can purchase one of the same spec, sites keep showing me 8uf ones as being the compatible part, any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

That device is a line EMI (R.F.I.) filter P/N 4213 078 52551, not directly related to the motor operation, despite the similar packaging to some run or start capacitors.

It's a separate part from the motor run capacitor and should be checked too (it could go open). But it sounds from the symptom (runs when hand-started) that it's the 8uF run capacitor that has lost capacitance or gone completely open.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so my tumble dryer won't soon unless I help it turn and a video said I need to replace the capacitor which I believed this was, can't see any other part so this must do the same job?

Comment: No, it does **not** do the same job. It's called a R.F.I. filter in the schematic. Look for the 8uF capacitor P/N 4213 092 08091.

Comment: Thanks, I get you, you have been very helpful, it must be located down by the mirror, I'll have a look 

Comment: Found it, it's 8uf after all, thanks Spehro 